# how to pass null value to a method in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am having the method like,

```
public void sample(string roll-no,string name)
{
         //my code
}
```

and calling this method like,

```
sample("12us001",string.Empty);
```

But it showing the error as,"THE OVERLOADED METHOD HAS SOME INVALID ARGUMENTS."

how to pass this null argument???

Comment: just use... `null`?

Comment: `string.Empty` is not the same as `null`. It is `""`

Comment: The `-` is invalid in c#. Change it to `_`.

Comment: i already used null and " " .but same error

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You are asking how to pass null but you show that you are trying to pass `String.Empty`. An empty string is not a null reference. You also don't get this exception if you pass `String.Empty`.

Comment: You **need to provide** a [mcve]. We have to copy-paste-and-run your code to see your error. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a hyphen in a param name. Change to

```
public void sample(string rollno,string name)
{
         //my code
}
```

and it works.

if you want to pass a null in.. simply pass in null as a parameter when calling.

```
sample("12us001",null)
```

I've added the below to demonstrate how an overloaded version of your sample method may work.. and may be a cause of the error

```
public void sample(string rollno)
        {
            sample(rollno,null);
        }

        public void sample(string rollno,string name)
        {
            if (name == null)
            {
                //Do something here
            }
        }
```

You may need to handle the null if the sample method when passed in.

Comment: i already used null and " " but it showing the same error.

Comment: @jeyanthi: the error suggests that you have an overloaded `sample`-method, show all.

Comment: Whats the error. If you pass a null into method then there's a good change that you will get an error if you are acting upon the nullable parameter.

Answer (score 1):

firstly lets remove that "-"

```
public void sample(string rollno, string name)
{
    //your code
}
```

Having a method like this I can give nulls to it like this ...

```
sample(null, null);
```

The exception is quite specific in this case "overloaded method" implies that it's possible you have another version of this method ... for example ...

```
public void sample(string rollno, int number)
{
    //your code
}
```

In this case, the above call might result in that error. 
I would suggest that you look in to the overloads and see where your call "might" result in an incorrect call to another overload of your method.